# Can I get 2560 x1600 resolution on my dell 3007wfp-hc using the hdmi cable connection on my dell I660s desktop/

Tags: hdmi, high-resolution

I have a dell monitor 3007wfp-hc with dual link  dvi 25 pin cable connection. We just bought a dell desktop I660s which has a hdmi cable connection what can I do to get 2560  1600 resolution.Can I upgrade my video output? I have a integrated video card Intel HD graphics (dell)

Comment: Difficult to tell, I believe your PC has an Intel integrated GPU which may or may not be able to be used at that resolution, the monitor used DVI-D so should work with an HDMI to DVI converter, they are pretty cheap on eBay.

Comment: Yes, I am using HDMI to dvi converter and my max resolution is 1280x800.My graphics is integrated Intel(r)HD with a max resolution of 1280x800. How can I upgrade my graphics

Answer (score 1):

Took me hours to resolve this, so posting for others in the hope they find it quicker. [From here](http://en.community.dell.com/owners-club/alienware/f/3746/t/19993880).

> The only resolutions officially supported on the 10 year old 3007WFP-HC are 1280x800 60Hz and 2560x1600 60Hz. But you must be using a DVI-D DL out port on the computer and DVI-D DL to DVI-D DL cable. Using HDMI, DP, or mDP outs from a computer with any combination of converters or cabling will not get 2560x1600 60Hz. They might get 1280x800 60Hz but Dell never tested them.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

To get 2560x1600 resolution from that HDMI port it would require HDMI spec 1.3.  I'm not sure but I find it unlikely your Integrated Graphics would support that.

The best solution is to put a Low profile PCI express video card in the expansion slot.  If you got a graphics card with a Dual Link DVI or equivalent port it would definately support that high resolution.

[Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102958) is a possible Video Card

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but the monitor in question displays only 1280x800 and below with any cable other than a dual link dvi-d. An HDMI to DVI-D cable didn't work, nor did DVI-D single link. When the dual link is used, multiple resolutions up to 2560x1600 are available. The monitor auto switches to lower resolutions for games (1920x1080). I'm using an NVIDIA GTX 1060 for graphics. Great monitor.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your post.  Are you saying that the answer is to use a dual link DVI-D cable?  Please [edit] your post to be clearer.